# Design window in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I am beginner in c# universal app development and also in visual studio. I was seeing tutorial videos in YouTube. But I have a basic problem! I can't find Design window in visual studio!
I take this screenshot from video.
[image]

I found `Shift+f7`. but it doesn't work!
Can anybody help me please?
I didn't know where should I ask this question! So I'm Sorry.

Comment: What you have in VS? And are you open the "xaml" file?

Comment: @Alex Yes. I work in UWP. I'm working on `xaml` file. all of videos are based on design form! but I can't find that! Tnx

Comment: Maybe you have detached it and it's open in another tab, or window. If `View->Designer` doesn't work maybe you installation is corrupted. Also try clicking the `.xaml` file.

Comment: @null Thank you. just this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably didn't enable the XAML designer.

To solve this issue, you can enable it by clicking the `Tools`->`Options...`->`XAML Designer`:

[image]

You can enable it by checking the `Enable XAML Designer` and then click `OK` button, and this action will be applied after you restart your VS.